# Modifying the behavior of <Alt>Tab (possibly) using Compiz

Tags: 11.04, compiz, gnome-classic, window-management

I have set up Compiz and my desktop in a way that I really like that maximizes my screen real estate on my 10' netbook, but there is a small annoyance that I would like to know if I could change.

### The set up

Ubuntu 11.04 using Ubuntu Classic with Compiz on an Asus eee 1015PEM.  I have a 3x3 desktop wall with all windows set to maximize on creation, and a single gnome-panel at the top that is set to auto-hide.  I'm using the Static Application switcher plugin for controlling my Tab behavior, but I'm not necessarily attached to it.  The modification I've made to that plugin is that I have set Tab to cycle between all windows on all workspaces, instead of just the windows on the current workspace.

### The problem

I would like Tab to cycle between any windows on the current workspace before other workspaces.  For example, if I have chrome on workspace (1,1), gedit on workspace (1,2), and I open a terminal on workspace (1,2), I would like the tab order to be terminal, gedit, chrome, regardless of the time of creation.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This is the new capability available in 11.10 - I dont think this is possible in 11.04.

Comment: Really? That is fantastic, considering it'll be out in just a few days.  I guess I'll just wait until then and bear with it for another week.  Thanks

Comment: @fossfreedom will you please add that as an answer ?

Comment: And a very fine answer it it, thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst 11.04 doesnt have this capability, you be glad to know that there is a useful new option in 11.10 (oneiric).

In CCSM there is an option to *bias* the windows on the current workspace/viewport.  What this means is that all the windows in the viewport appear in <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switcher before other windows in other workspaces

[image]

**how to change**

In CCSM use the option highlighted:

[image]